# Responsive BootStrap-Table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-table, bulma

(video reference https://streamable.com/grv9iy)

I am using the https://bootstrap-table.com specifically the Bulma stylesheet version (not the same as regular bootstrap stylesheet!) to make my table. As can be seen in the video, the table is not responsive, and instead, when the table overflows on screen it just becomes scrollable. Any ideas?

Code is below, but NOTE! The code relies on Flask (python) to pass it the var's for table.

or codepen https://codepen.io/OOUZI/pen/XWaBRxN

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.2/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/themes/bulma/bootstrap-table-bulma.min.css">
    {% include 'js_html/table-extensions-css.html' %}
<body>
{% include 'topbar.html' %}
{% include 'js_html/quickview.html' %}
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 110.25rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  white-space: normal;
}

.instructor {
  width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.label {
  font-size: .725rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: +1.3px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.searchBar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

#searchQueryInput {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.8rem;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 1.625rem;
  padding: 0 3.5rem 0 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#searchQuerySubmit {
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 2.8rem;
  margin-left: -3.5rem;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#searchQuerySubmit:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<style>
@-webkit-keyframes spinAround{from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}to{-webkit-transform:rotate(359deg);transform:rotate(359deg)}}@keyframes spinAround{from{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}to{-webkit-transform:rotate(359deg);transform:rotate(359deg)}}.pageloader{bottom:0;left:0;position:absolute;right:0;top:0}.pageloader{position:fixed;padding-top:2em;background:#00d1b2;background:#00d1b2;z-index:999998;transition:transform .35s ease-out,-webkit-transform .35s ease-out;will-change:transform}.pageloader.is-white{background-color:#fff;background:#fff}.pageloader.is-white::after{border-color:#0a0a0a;-webkit-animation:loader-figure-white 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-white 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-white .title{color:#0a0a0a}.pageloader.is-black{background-color:#0a0a0a;background:#0a0a0a}.pageloader.is-black::after{border-color:#fff;-webkit-animation:loader-figure-black 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-black 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-black .title{color:#fff}.pageloader.is-light{background-color:#f5f5f5;background:#f5f5f5}.pageloader.is-light::after{border-color:#363636;-webkit-animation:loader-figure-light 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-light 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-light .title{color:#363636}.pageloader.is-dark{background-color:#363636;background:#363636}.pageloader.is-dark::after{border-color:#f5f5f5;-webkit-animation:loader-figure-dark 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-dark 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-dark .title{color:#f5f5f5}.pageloader.is-primary{background-color:#00d1b2;background:#00d1b2}.pageloader.is-primary::after{border-color:#fff;-webkit-animation:loader-figure-primary 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-primary 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-primary .title{color:#fff}.pageloader.is-link{background-color:#3273dc;background:#3273dc}.pageloader.is-link::after{border-color:#fff;-webkit-animation:loader-figure-link 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-link 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-link .title{color:#fff}.pageloader.is-info{background-color:#209cee;background:#209cee}.pageloader.is-info::after{border-color:#fff;-webkit-animation:loader-figure-info 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-info 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-info .title{color:#fff}.pageloader.is-success{background-color:#23d160;background:#23d160}.pageloader.is-success::after{border-color:#fff;-webkit-animation:loader-figure-success 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-success 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-success .title{color:#fff}.pageloader.is-warning{background-color:#ffdd57;background:#ffdd57}.pageloader.is-warning::after{border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);-webkit-animation:loader-figure-warning 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-warning 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-warning .title{color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)}.pageloader.is-danger{background-color:#ff3860;background:#ff3860}.pageloader.is-danger::after{border-color:#fff;-webkit-animation:loader-figure-danger 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure-danger 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader.is-danger .title{color:#fff}.pageloader:not(.is-bottom-to-top){-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);transform:translateY(-100%)}.pageloader.is-bottom-to-top{-webkit-transform:translateY(100%);transform:translateY(100%)}.pageloader.is-left-to-right{-webkit-transform:translateX(-100%);transform:translateX(-100%)}.pageloader.is-right-to-left{-webkit-transform:translateX(100%);transform:translateX(100%)}.pageloader.is-active:not(.is-left-to-right),.pageloader.is-active:not(.is-right-to-left){-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}.pageloader.is-active.is-left-to-right,.pageloader.is-active.is-right-to-left{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);transform:translateX(0)}.pageloader::after{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;display:block;border-radius:100%;content:'';z-index:9999;-webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);transform:translate(-50%,-50%);width:0;height:0;box-sizing:border-box;border:0 solid #fff;-webkit-animation:loader-figure 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1);animation:loader-figure 1.15s infinite cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)}.pageloader .title{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);transform:translateX(-50%);margin:2em 0 0 0;font-size:.875em;letter-spacing:.1em;line-height:1.5em;color:#fff;white-space:nowrap}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-white{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#0a0a0a}29%{background-color:#0a0a0a}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-white{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#0a0a0a}29%{background-color:#0a0a0a}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-black{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-black{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-light{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#363636}29%{background-color:#363636}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-light{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#363636}29%{background-color:#363636}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-dark{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#f5f5f5}29%{background-color:#f5f5f5}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-dark{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#f5f5f5}29%{background-color:#f5f5f5}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-primary{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-primary{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-link{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-link{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-info{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-info{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-success{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-success{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-warning{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)}29%{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-warning{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)}29%{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.7)}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@-webkit-keyframes loader-figure-danger{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}@keyframes loader-figure-danger{0%{height:0;width:0;background-color:#fff}29%{background-color:#fff}30%{height:2em;width:2em;background-color:transparent;border-width:1em;opacity:1}100%{height:2em;width:2em;border-width:0;opacity:0;background-color:transparent}}
</style>
<div onload="function()" class="pageloader is-active is-link is-bottom-to-top"><span class="title">Pageloader</span></div>
<script>
setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('pageloader').style.display = 'none'
    document.getElementById('pageloader').style.display = 'none';
}, 2000)
<script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <table data-show-columns-toggle-all="true" classes="table-sm" data-sortable="true" data-filter-control="true" class="is-narrow table-responsive" data-toggle="table" data-search-highlight="true" data-advanced-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-fullscreen="true" data-id-table="advancedTable" data-mobile-responsive="true" data-sticky-header="true" data-pagination="true" data-search="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sortable="false" searchable="false">Favorite</th>
      <th data-sortable="false" searchable="false">Image</th>
      <th data-field="CRN" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">CRN</th>
      <th data-field="Subject" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Subject</th>
      <th data-field="Course" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Course</th>
      <th data-field="Credits" data-sortable="true" searchable="true" >Credits</th>
      <th data-field="Title" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Title</th>
      <th data-field="Days" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Days</th>
      <th data-field="Times" data-sortable="true" searchable="true" >Times</th>
      <th data-field="Instructors" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Instructor</th>
      <th data-field="Attribute" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Attribute</th>
      <th data-field="InstructorDiff" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Instructors Difficulty</th>
      <th data-field="InstructorRating" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Instructors Rating</th>
      <th data-field="WouldTakeAgain" data-sortable="true" searchable="true">Would Take Again</th>
      <th data-field="Comments" data-sortable="false" searchable="false">Comments</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  {% for course in courses %}
    <tr>
    <th scope="favorite_course">
    <form action="/favorite_courses/api/add_course/{{course.id}}" method="post">
        <button class="button is-success" name="foo" value="upvote">+</button>
    </form>
    </th>
    
    {% if instructors[course.instr]['image'] == None or instructors[course.instr]['image'] == "" %}
      <div class="image">
      </div>
    <td class="is-image-cell">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://www.yu.edu/sites/default/files/default_images/Placeholder_0.png" style="max-height:100px;width:100px;" class="is-rounded instr-profile">
      </div>
      </td>
    {% else %}
        <div class="image">
        </div>
      <td class="is-image-cell">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="{{instructors[course.instr]['image']}}" class="is-rounded instr-profile" style="max-height:100px;width:100px;">
        </div>
        </td>
    {% endif %}
      <td data-label="CRN">{{course.crn}}</td>
      <td data-label="Subject">{{course.subj}}</td>
      <td data-label="Course">{{course.crse}}</td>
      <td data-label="Credits">{{course.cred}}</td>
      <td class="instructor" data-label="Title">{{course.title}}</td>
      <td data-label="Days">{{course.days}}</td>
      <td data-label="Times">{{course.time}}</td>
      <td data-label="Instructor">{{course.instr}}</td>
      <td data-label="Attribute">{{course.attribute}}</td>
      
      <td data-width="10" data-width-unit="%" data-label="Instructors Difficulty" class="is-progress-cell">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
          <p class="bd-notification is-info"><center>{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}%</center></p>
          <div class="columns is-mobile">
            <div class="column">
              {% if instructors[course.instr]['profDiff'] | int >= 75 %}
              <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-danger" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}</progress></td>
              {% elif instructors[course.instr]['profDiff'] | int >= 50 %}
              <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-warning" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}</progress></td>
              {% else %}
              <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-primary" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profDiff']}}</progress></td>
              {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>

      <td data-label="Instructors Rating" class="is-progress-cell">
      <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <p class="bd-notification is-info"><center>{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}%</center></p>
        <div class="columns is-mobile">
          <div class="column">
          {% if instructors[course.instr]['profRating'] | int >= 75 %}
          <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-primary" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}</progress></td>
          {% elif instructors[course.instr]['profRating'] | int>= 50 %}
          <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-warning" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}</progress></td>
          {% else %}
          <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-danger" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profRating']}}</progress></td>
          {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
      
      <td data-label="Would Take Again" class="is-progress-cell">
      <div class="columns">
      <div class="column">
        <p class="bd-notification is-info"><center>{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}%</center></p>
        <div class="columns is-mobile">
          <div class="column">
            {% if instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain'] | int >= 75 %}
            <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-primary" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}</progress>
            {% elif instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain'] | int >= 50 %}
            <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-warning" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}</progress>
            {% else %}
            <progress max="100" class="progress is-small is-danger" value="{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}">{{instructors[course.instr]['profWouldTakeAgain']}}</progress>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </td>
    <!-- {% include 'course_list/comments.html' %}  -->
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/themes/bulma/bootstrap-table-bulma.min.js"></script>
{% include 'js_html/table-extensions-js.html' %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you upload code to codepen or jsfiddle to reproduce the issue? So we could have ability to edit code. For example, exclude python and add only HTML, CSS, JS with 1 row of static data just to see that unresponsive behavior. :)

Comment: Ill comment again here when done give me a few! Very reasonable haha.

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap, [Datatables](https://datatables.net) offers a Bootstrap designed responsive table!

Comment: @Tadas https://codepen.io/OOUZI/pen/XWaBRxN There

Comment: @BeerusDev I really like / want to use bootstrap-table. I appreciate advice though!

Answer (score 1):

Now I understand your issue. [Look at this page](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/large-columns.html). This is default behavior for Boostrap Table framework. When you exceed certain amount of Columns then it enables horizontal scrollbar. And what I seen many times before - this is normal behavior.

Look, when you leave only first 11 Cells - scrollbar hides:

[image]

Possible workarounds:

1. Use the same settings button I used to hide columns above and create default configuration that page loads only with the most important columns until it will be responsive.
2. Reduce paddings, reduce font-size, image size, etc.
3. If this table will be used widely by multiple returning visitors - use Javascript localStorage and make default configuration for each user from their selection on what to hide/show using that button in 1st step. Just add functionality to remember what each individual user wanted to see and show the same Columns for him when he visits again.

Hope I helped you but you cannot do much in this case since it's a table. You can't use CSS and force Column to break into another Row like DIV elements usualy does, it just would look terrible for table...

**Update:**

Adding this CSS will make your table responsive for 1920x.... screens:

```
.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table thead th .th-inner {
   padding: 0.15em;
   font-size: 11px;
}

.button, .file-cta, .file-name, .input, .pagination-ellipsis, .pagination-link, .pagination-next, .pagination-previous, .select select, .textarea  {
   font-size: 0.7rem;
}

.table.is-narrow td, .table.is-narrow th {
   padding: 0.25em 0.3em;
}

.bootstrap-table .fixed-table-container .table td {
   font-size: 13px;
}
```

[image]

**P.S - It would be ideal to get rid of at least 1-3 Columns.**

**Update 2:**

By the way, your last colums will be only percent values with progress bars. You can either:

- decrease max-width for progress bars and comment labels; or
- you can make circle shaped progress bars around percent values.

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to just reduce the overall size of the element? So its smaller but it fits.

Comment: I will try to resize it and edit my original answer. :)

Comment: @OzeBotach take a look. Managed to make it responsive with some tweaks. Little play around and you could make it responsive for XL and LG screens, for MD/XS screens you will need to leave it with horizontal scrollbar. If this answer your original question - don't forget to mark this answer as "answered". Always happy to help. :)

Comment: Hmmm I really appreciate this addition, but it seems it shrinks the test but not the rows themselves which waste space. Additionally it looks very awkward. I don't mean to sound unappreciative, just not the most ideal way. I am gonna see if I can mess with this to fix some things up.

Comment: I tried everything, Bulma does not allow to shrink the progress bars for some reason :/

Comment: I actually wanted to add circle progress bars, I messed with the idea but no luck getting one to work but that's bc my schedule is crazy and don't have too much time to mess with it, I should find time for that.

Comment: Would be interesting if I can make a three-ring singular progress circle. with a small legend

Comment: Do you have live example of progress bar so I could play with CSS? Regarding three-ring singular progress circle - I can't help with that, never did that. You can try to Google/ask additional question here in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239102/discussion-between-oze-botach-and-tadas).

Comment: @OzeBotach If my question answered your issue - please mark it as answered. If you have another issues, then create another question. Thanks :)